# Download abuse with php Content-Disposition: attachment and readfile

Tags: php, header, attachment, readfile, content-disposition

I'm having a download abuse issue with php Content-Disposition: attachment and readfile. It seems that my problem is with readfile, because although this script works, whether or not the client closes their browser, readfile reads the entire contents of the mp4, setting up the possibility of abuse with scripts initiating the download and immediately closing the progress. Something, somewhere, is running a script which clicks this link hundreds of times per second, running my php script and immediately cancelling their download, but my server is preparing that entire file to be offloaded each time.

Here's the script I'm running, when the user/abuser clicks a download link:

```
<?php
// get MP4 address
$MP4Address = $_GET["MP4Address"];

// We'll be outputting a MOV
header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );

$filename = basename($MP4Address);

// Name file
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

// Source file
readfile($MP4Address);
?>
```

I suspect that readfile is the culprit here, but without it, the client will receive an empty file. There must be a more modern, proper way of doing this, but I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: Hopefully, there's more to the real script which you haven't shown because it's not relevant, but just in case: never trust input from the user! The script as shown allows anyone to download any file from your server - your security configuration, your PHP code, anything they like.

Comment: @IMSoP nice catch. OP, this is a big one and probably the reason why someone is doing this. Someone is likely using this script to perform an "amplification attack" against a third party. All they have to do is tickle your script as they are now, close the connection, and for the cost of a couple bytes of making the request they can make your server download many megabytes or gigabytes of data from the target, potentially overloading it. You need to lock down who can use this script, and where it can download data from.

Comment: Right, I hadn't twigged that it could also be used as a transparent proxy for any URL, as long as allow_url_fopen is switched on. I'm really hoping this is just simplified code for our benefit, otherwise it is a very very bad idea indeed.

Comment: Yes nice catch. readfile should be using the address and subdirectories typed in with the variable $filename, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've called [`ignore_user_abort(true)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort) PHP should get the signal that the connection has been aborted and cease execution. But it's possible that once you're inside the `readfile()` call PHP is not able to watch for that signal since it's busy doing low-level IO.

I would say you've got 2 options, the first being to simply write some code to detect and block the person that's abusing your service. You downloads are already backed by a PHP script, so adding in a bit of checking and filtering should be relatively simple.

The other would be to replace the `readfile()` call with a bit of [admittedly less efficient] code that should give PHP some breathing space to look for user aborts.

```php
function read_file($filename, $chunksize=4096) {
  if( ! $fh = fopen($filename, 'rb') ) {
    throw new \Exception('Failed to open file');
  }
  while($chunk = fread($fh, $chunksize)) {
    echo $chunk;
  }
  fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: Although this was implemented, the site is being attacked by the downloads being abused in the same way (downloading, stopping download, repeat). I think this should check for an abort.